# Date comparison validation in angular

Tags: angularjs, validation, date

I have 2 dates:  1.start and 2.end
format is like this.

```
12/4/2017               console.log(startDate);
12/20/2017              console.log(endDate);
```

I am writing a validation to check if the end date is bigger than start date throw error,but it is not working.
this is what i have tried:

```
var startDate = new Date(this.formB['startDateVal']).toLocaleDateString();
var endDate=new Date(this.formB['dueDateVal']).toLocaleDateString();
```

this is my condition:

```
if(endDate<startDate){
      this.bucketMsgClass='fielderror';
      this.bucketSuccessMsg = 'End Date is must lower than Start Date.';
 }
```

where am i doing wrong.?

Comment: You're comparing strings, instead of comparing dates. strings compare lexicographically, not chronologically.

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us what went wrong. Are we supposed to guess, and then help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always just subtracted one of the dates from the other. If the result is negative, then Date 1 is before Date 2.

```
var d1 = new Date("12/12/2017");
var d2 = new Date("12/13/2017");

console.log(d1 - d2) // -86400000 (exactly 1 day in milliseconds)
```

So

```
if (d1 - d2 < 0) {
    // d1 is smaller
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Going through this link that explains comparing dates in javascript would probably help you understand the problem and solve it.

[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)